# Problem specifying entrypoint in Amazon ECS Task

Tags: bash, docker, amazon-ecs

I am trying to replicate the advice for running Nginx and Certbot in containers in an Amazon ECS environment.  The advice I have been following can be found [here](https://medium.com/@pentacent/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71).  This has been great but I am struggling with the last step which is to ensure the certificates are updated in the future.  For example the recommended command for Nginx is:

```
command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
```

On a local container this worked but ECS needs this in the string array format so I used the following command (which worked locally):

```
command: ["/bin/sh","-c","while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\""]
```

I added the same to the ECS console. However, the task fails to start and in the output I get:

```
/bin/sh: 1: wait: Illegal number: 1{!}
nginx: invalid option: "off"
/bin/sh: 1: ": not found
```

The command in the Task JSON looks like this:

```
"command": [
        "/bin/sh",
        "-c",
        "while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \\\"daemon off;\\\""
      ],
```

It looks like this is failing to interpret correctly but I am not sure how I should be quoting (or escaping) this for it to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give "command my version" a try?
I believe you have a problem because you replaced the ' by "

```
command original:      "/bin/sh   -c  'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
command your version: ["/bin/sh","-c","while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\""]
command my version:   ["/bin/sh","-c",'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"']
```

Comment: I gave it a go but the "..." are added by the ECS console converting the command to JSON. So it then wraps the '...' quoted command in "...".  The result I got was:  /bin/sh: 1: while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\": not found.  BTW I also tried escaping the '...' using \'...\' and got:  /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "do" unexpected

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the magic combination that satisfied both `JSON` and `sh` quoting needs... and fixed a script error on the way.  The final stance was to enter this in the ECS console:

```
/bin/sh,-c,while :; do sleep 6h & wait $!; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g 'daemon off'
```

This resulted in `JSON` that looks like:

```
"command": [
        "sh",
        "-c",
        "while :; do sleep 6h & wait $!; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
      ],
```

For some reason in the ECS environment I was able to use the much more direct reference to the child PID `$!` rather than the more obscure `SS{!}` needed for the `docker-compose` world.